# Query get specific value in opencart

Tags: php, mysql, opencart

Im biggner in opencart my issue is I add field in product table called (model_choice) , in the product.tpl page in path (catalog/view/theme/default/template/product/product.tpl) I want to get the value of the row (model_choice) for the selected product I already get the product id with `$this->request->get['product_id']` I try to get the value of (model_choice) with

```
$sql = $this->db->query('SELECT model_choice 
                        FROM '.DB_PREFIX.'product 
                        WHERE product_id = ' . $this->request->get['product_id']);
$id = $sql ->model_choice;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`$id = $sql->row['model_choice'];` - Try this.

`print_r($sql->rows); \\Shows all results.`

Refer this link: [How to become an OpenCart guru?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13478995/how-to-become-an-opencart-guru)

Comment: i try to vote up but vote up require 15 reputation and i only have 5 reputation